# Настройки службы через графический интерфейс

Tags: c#, .net, service

Есть служба, которая работает с подключенной к ней библиотекой dll. Библиотека хранит некоторые настройки в файле App.Config. Вопрос: как дать возможность пользователю менять эти настройки вручную? Есть идея создать отдельное оконное приложение, которое бы изменяло поля в файле App.Config. Хотелось бы найти оптимальное решение.

Comment: Эээ... А вы уверены, что это работает? Если я не ошибаюсь, app.config для DLL вообще игнорируется.

Comment: Да, работает. В проекте с библиотекой лежит файл app., в нем значения переменных, все как и планировалось.